# Web scraping using Apify

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, puppeteer, apify

I'm trying to scrape URLs from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hedge_funds

Specifically, I'm trying to use Apify to scrape that page and return a list of URLs from anchor tags present in the HTML. In my console, I expect to see the value of the `href` attribute of one or more anchor tags that exist on the target page in a property called `myValue`. I also expect to see the page title in a property called `title`. Instead, I just see the following `URL` property and its value.

[image]

My Apify actor uses the Puppeteer platform. So I'm using a `pageFunction` [similar to the way Puppeteer uses it](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

Below is a screen shot of the Apify UI just before I run it.

[image]

Page function

```
function pageFunction( context ) {
    // called on every page the crawler visits, use it to extract data from it
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var result = {
        title: $('.wikitable').text,
        myValue: $('a[href]').text,
    };
    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this one? apify/web-scraper

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, `text` is a function so you need to add parentheses:

```
var result = {
    title: $('.wikitable').text(),
    myValue: $('a[href]').text(),
};
```

But note that this will probably not do what you expect anyway - it will return text of all matched elements. You probably need to use `jQuery's each()` function (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate the found elements, push some values from them to an array and return the array from your page function.

Answer (score 0):

The page seems to be loaded by JavaScript so actually I have to use asynchronous code.